# Can't run PowerShell as admin inside of Webstorm

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, webstorm

I am trying to figure out how to run PowerShell as an admin embedded in Webstorm. I can run PowerShell as non-admin in Webstorm, but when I try to run PowerShell as admin inside Webstorm I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY
```

I have tried the following things:

1) Make a shortcut of PowerShell, set PowerShell shortcut to run as admin, start Webstorm, set path of terminal to PowerShell shortcut, save and restart Webstorm, open Webstorm and start embedded PowerShell.

2) Same as above but I did set both Webstorm and PowerShell as run as admin at the same time.
Both of these give me the same error as above.